# Coldfusion tmpCache in auto scaling group/multiple instance

Tags: coldfusion, autoscaling, coldfusion-2018, cfadmin

I was using some functions inside

> C:\ColdFusion2018\cfusion\tmpCache\CFFileServlet

on my Coldfusion, however after moved the setup into auto scaling group, when there is >1 instance/server running, my application failed to load properly the modules inside the folder such as captcha, cfchart.

The error returned is 404, seems like the request unable to track back which server it used to generate the captcha or cfchart image.

Is there any setting to fix this? Such as changing this tmpCache folder into a File Share maybe?

Comment: The instances each use their own temp folder. If you have one server with multiple instances, you need to update all the instances to reference the same shared folder. You might look into using Amazon S3 instead of a local file share. If the app grows to multiple servers with multiple instances, you'll really need to avoid local files.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno How can I change it reference to the same shared folder? I search through documentation and settings inside Coldfusion Admin, seem like cannot found any useful setting to change the reference path.

Comment: What about mapped drives or network paths?

Comment: @DanBracuk it's the same as shared folder i mentioned. I can provision a network shared folder, but the issue is I can't find any settings on coldfusion which allowing me change the 'tmpCache' path to there. So I guess this is not a solution unless coldfusion allow me change to a new path.